# Failed to release into Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-release, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to release the vision_visp stack into Fuerte but I have the following
error message:

```
ERROR: No rosdep rule can be found for key [u'boost']

This release script uses rosdep 2, which does not read files from
<stack-name>/rosdep.yaml.  Please see the following documentation on
how to add the rules you need for release:

http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html
```

I assume that Boost is part of the core rosdep dependencies that are already
in rosdep 2 so I don't understand what I should do.

By the rosdep 2 documentation indicates that dependency lookup is done through /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d. This directory does not exist on my computer, neither does /opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d. Is it normal?

I do not use shadow repos. Does it explain why it does not work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29095/failed-to-release-into-fuerte/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep/html/overview.html#installing-rosdep

rosdep requires an initialization by running

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

This will first update (or create) the system rules in /opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d and then update your local user's cache (in ~/.ros). You could also update rosdep itself, I believe the newest version gives a warning when running with an empty sources.list.d. I had to learn this the hard way too ;)

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-03-05**:
Thanks, I misses this. Now it is way better :) It probably would be intersting that rosdep 2 suggests to run the following command when no DB exists...